# Understanding Latency and Jitter

Tags: latency

Analyzed 2 different internet connection. Details are as:

```
Net-1:

Download Speed: 2699 kbps (337.4 KB/sec transfer rate)
Upload Speed: 4737 kbps (592.1 KB/sec transfer rate)
Latency: 172 ms
Jitter: 50 ms

Net-2:

Download Speed: 1711 kbps (337.4 KB/sec transfer rate)
Upload Speed: 505 kbps (592.1 KB/sec transfer rate)
Latency: 40 ms
Jitter: 19 ms
```

What I know about "Latency" is that it's good if less and same goes for "Jitter". So, why come in this case an internet connection, with higher bandwidth, have higher "Latency and Jitter" then a connection less bandwidth?

Comment: Good in what way?  Higher bandwidth?  How are you measuring latency?

Comment: You are asking an unclear question and making some assumptions that may or may not be correct, depending on the application of the network. You need to narrow the scope.

Comment: @RonTrunk I ran speed test on both connections, my questions is why the connection with higher bandwidth has higher latency and jitter.

Comment: Mostly because bandwidth and latency are not dependent on each other.  When you say "speed test," what speed test?   We need a lot more details to give you a useful answer.  By the way, if this is about your home network, that's off-topic here.

Comment: Ah, but that's not what you asked.

Comment: jitter is the variation in certain value from its mean value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are equating "good" with "perceived speed." Latency and jitter, *in general*, have little to do with bandwidth.

Latency is a measure of the rather fixed limits of physics. Distance, routing and switching delays all contribute to the latency between any two nodes. Higher or lower latency doesn't make a link good or bad. Lower latency is *better*, but there's usually very little that can be done about it. (speed of light being what it is and all.)

Jitter is the variability in latency. Jitter is "bad". It's a function of queuing, buffers, processing loads, and generally the fact that there's other traffic competing for the link. Lower speed links will tend to have higher jitter due to the delay one packet will cause for any other.

Protocols can easily deal with latency -- i.e. by transmitting more data without any acknowledgement. But jitter is problematic because of it's randomness and very nature -- sending more traffic could overflow a buffer.

So... why is net-1 "worse"? It's a longer link, passing through more hops, and thus meeting with more congestion? (you've given *nothing* on which to base an actual factual answer)

Comment: Got it. I was making a mistake in looking at "Bandwidth" and "Latency & Jitter" together.